# Mysql ver 5.7.15 Timestamp wrong

Tags: mysql, linux

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to read this request for information.

I have an issue with MySql verson '5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1' running on linux

now and timestamp are not working

select now(); returns -> '2021-01-11 02:33:54'

system date is Wed 19 Apr 2023 04:11:33 PM EDT

I have restarted my server with power down and restart.
Tried just restarting mysql

Please see attached image.

The issue continues.

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Does this happen if you use the CLI mysql client, or only with Workbench?

Comment: I have localhost turned off only connect via ssh or  mysql workbench

Comment: `mysql -h servername` should allow you to connect from the terminal.

Comment: What does sysdate{} function return?

Comment: select sysdate() -> '2021-01-11 03:13:11'
linux date -> Wed 19 Apr 2023 05:20:04 PM EDT

Comment: In this case I suspect that your mysql runs on a different server than the one you check your date on.

Answer (score -2):

`now()` returns the timestamp in the timezone of your database connection session.  Some clients will set this every time you connect.  You can do:

```
select @@SESSION.time_zone, @@GLOBAL.time_zone
```

to see the session timezone and what it would be if left unchanged.  "SYSTEM" means using the system timezone (/etc/timezone for linux).

If you want to get US Eastern time regardless of the connection settings, you can do

```
select convert_tz(utc_timestamp(), '+00:00', 'America/New_York')
```

(assuming you have run mysql_tzinfo_to_sql to populate the msyql timezone tables).

Comment: thanks for your comment. when I cat out timezone it returns: cat timezone 
America/New_York

Comment: If it were a timezone problem it would just be off by a few hours. He's getting more than 2 years difference.

Comment: and what does the `select @@SESSION.time_zone, @@GLOBAL.time_zone` show?  is your mysql server in fact running on the host you are connecting from?  what does `TZ=GMT0 date` show on the host the mysql server is running on?

Comment: select @@SESSION.time_zone, @@GLOBAL.time_zone  returns 'SYSTEM', 'SYSTEM'

Comment: what does `select @@hostname` show?  sounds to me like your server is running on a different host and that host has a messed up time

Comment: wow.. I was hitting the wrong sever. Thanks very much. I had a backup/uat server running and connected to it by mistake. This sever is not not allowed to see outside world. time was off. Thanks again

Comment: Please be careful hat you mark as an accepted answer! It seems at the moment as if the aswer to your question were timezone setting differences! It would be better if you simply deleted this question!